# Python md5 hashes comparison

Tags: python, hash, md5

I'm trying to compare hashes using Python, but I'm stuck with this problem:

```
print ('-- '+hashesFile[h])
print ('-> ' +hashlib.md5(wordsFile[j]).hexdigest())   

-- 5d21e42d34fc1563bb2c73b3e1811357
-> 5d21e42d34fc1563bb2c73b3e1811357
```

But this comparison is never true:

```
if (hashesFile[h] == hashlib.md5(wordsFile[j]).hexdigest()):
 print ('ok')
```

I searched for a solution and tried to encode the string before compare them, but is don't work anyway.

Cheers!!

Comment: Are you sure both strings contains no whitespace chars like space or newline?

Comment: Are both the strings of the same type (e.g. are they unicode strings, binary strings etc.)? Try printing `repr()` of each of the values to see what Python thinks they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to print both as:

```
print '-- %r' % hashesFile[h]
print '-> %r' % hashlib.md5(wordsFile[j]).hexdigest())
```

then you'll see whats really inside.

I suppose that this will work for you:

```
if (hashesFile[h].strip() == hashlib.md5(wordsFile[j]).hexdigest()):
    print ('ok')
```